# How to access elements of one html in another html file using their id

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two html files ( file1.html and file2.html ).

In file2, I have 10 paragraphs each having a unique id . How can I access these paragraphs using their id in file1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you mean by "access".

Comment: Are you looking for a Javascript solution?

Comment: Access how? HTML can not access a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with Javascript using the `.getElementById` method. This can be accomplished via localStorage. Below are steps to save data from `file2` to the point where you're actually able to use it in `file1`

```js
you can use localStorage 
for example in file2.html you save data with
var thing = document.getElementById('id').value;
localStorage.something = thing ; 
then in your file1.html you can use it by
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=localStorage.something;
```